# Firing HREF on ipad app webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, ipad

I'm creating an download app installation webpage. However, I am using html to try to fire this link. 
The link fires, but sometimes a prompt appears that says Open in App Store, then when you click open it opens the installation pop up to install the app. Then, the other popup happens when you touch down and then move (ontouchmove), on the end of that it will create a prompt that safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid. I've tried force triggers and scripts, but nothing seems to work, maybe a new iso 9 thing.

```
<body  ontouchmove="event.preventDefault();" >
<a ontouchend="window.location='itms-services://?action=download-myapp';">

<div class="top" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:1024px;height:640px;background:u rl() no-repeat;"></div>

<div class="" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:1024px;height:640px;" ontouchstart='this.style.background="url() no-repeat"'  ontouchend='this.style.background=""'></div>

</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by some of those `<div>`s in your example, which don't seem to do anything.

Anyway, here's the very simple code I use on our intranet webpage, which lets users download & install our in-house iPhone app:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onInstall()
    {
        window.location = "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://......../MyIphoneApp.plist";
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div onclick="onInstall()">
        Download my iPhone app
    </div>
</body>
```

Remember that the URL which points to your .plist file must be `https`, not `http`.

(This is easy enough to do, by saving your .plist file into a Dropbox folder, and getting the Dropbox URL.)

Also, make sure you're using a $299 Apple Developer License (rather than a single-user $99 license), as you need this, to create Ad-Hoc & In-house apps.  And you need to use a Provisioning Profile which uses an Enterprise Certificate.

Get any of this wrong, and Xcode will happily let you create and Archive an Enterprise app, and it'll be a mess.  It might start downloading & installing onto the user's device, then give up, with a hopelessly misleading "Application cannot be installed *at this time*" type error.

Also make sure your .plist's Bundle Version Number exactly matches that of your project, otherwise, once again, it'll start downloading & installing, then just give up, with no explanation why (and nothing on the device's Logs).

I've burned many, *many*, hours chasing my tail, due to the complete lack of error reporting in this area...

Comment: I tried this code and although it's functional. When I click and move and let go, it doesn't not fire. I am trying tor resolve that problem.

Comment: Errr, you shouldn't be clicking, you should be tapping.  This is code for a webpage which should be viewed on an iPad or iPhone in Safari, and will then kick off the iOS process to install an in-house app.

Comment: Btw. get rid of the "onTouchMove" on your body.  Strip the code right back to the lines I've shown above, and say what happens when you run this on an iOS device.

Comment: The same problem still occurs when I am tapping and moving.